# Как распечатать символ стрелки?

Tags: linux, c

Выяснил, что символы стрелок имеют следующие ASCII коды:

```
72 - вверх
75 - влево
77 - вправо
80 - вниз
```

Но эти же коды имеют некоторые буквы в верхнем регистре.

Возможно, эта информация ошибочна, но при проверке мне никак не удалось напечатать символы стрелок.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать через обычный printf?
Поддерживается только ASCII.

Comment: @Abyx utf-8 не поддерживается (исполняется загрузчик ОС)

Comment: а если загрузить юникодный шрифт? какой загрузчик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

эти коды хоть и соответствуют стрелочкам, но не все так просто - они там составные. То есть, код стрелки - это два байта, а не один. И первый байт Вы забили указать.  Этот байт - 224. То есть, код стрелки вверх - 224 72. Вот только распечатать их нельзя. Это управляющие символы клавиатуры. Более того, их нет в стандартной аски таблице.

Когда то давно, когда был дос и нужны были стрелочки, делали кодогенераторы. То есть, готовиться своя таблица, в которой прописано отображение каждого символа. И можно взять часть символов, записать туда правильные картинки и использовать. Я даже не знаю, возможно ли это сейчас, но думаю, что все возможно. В любом случае, можно перевести видеорежим в графический и рисовать красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте эти коды:

```
ASCII value of character ↑: 24
ASCII value of character ↓: 25
ASCII value of character →: 26
ASCII value of character ←: 27
```

Comment: И какой терминал их нарисует?

Comment: Так работать, к сожалению, не будет

Comment: Действительно, зависит от терминала. Windows выводит стрелочки.